# Track downloaded videos watched progress on windows 10?

Tags: video, video-player, learning

Say I've a folder where there are subfolders and each subfolders have videos. I want a software where I can upload the main folder and from there I start watching the videos. I should be able to track my progress. i.e How many videos I've completed, how much percentage of total videos I've watched already. Is there a software for it? ie something like udemy does.

Comment: How should be progress tracked for each video file? Should starting at stopping count as completed or video should be played to the end to count? Should fast forwarding count as completed?

Comment: Yes fast forwarding should be counted as completed. Once I reach the end point of time of video(say 9.59 of 10.00 min video, it means I completed the video).

Answer (score 0):

Here is my quick attempt to add playback progress ("Played" column) for each file to [VideoPlayer](https://tomeko.net/software/VideoPlayer/) (mplayer GUI). Clicking on column header sorts files by the progress value.
[image: VideoPlayer 2.4.0.2]
Download link: https://tomeko.net/tmp/VideoPlayer_2_4_0_2.7z (9.34 MB, portable, 30 MB after unpacking). Mplayer copy (not the newest one, but still working well) is included in this archive.